# React router global header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I just started learning React, I'm trying to make a SPA blog, which has a global positioned fixed header.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
// import other components here

    render((
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/About" component={About} />
        <Route path="/Contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route path="*" component={Error} />
      </Router>
    ), document.getElementById('app'));
```

So, each routes has the same header and from my angular background, I would use header outside ui-view.

Its a good practice to import the header component in each individual page component, or can I add the header component on my `<Router><myHeader/><otherRoutes/></Router>`?

**Update:**

I was thinking to use something like this:

Routes component, where I define my routes:

```
class Routes extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <IndexRoute component={Home} />
                <Route path="/studio" component={Studio} />
                <Route path="/work" component={Work} />
                <Route path="*" component={Home} />
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

And then on main Index.js file I would like to render something like:

```
import Routes from './components/Routes';

render((
   <div>
      <div className="header">header</div>
      <Routes />
   </div>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Can someone explain me? Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

From my experience it can be good to define a layout component for your page, something like...

Layout Component

```
render() {
    return(
       <div>
          <Header />
             { this.props.children }
             /* anything else you want to appear on every page that uses this layout */
          <Footer />
       </div>
    );
}
```

You then import layout into each of your page components...

Contact Page Component

```
render() {
    return (
        <Layout>
           <ContactComponent />
           /* put all you want on this page within the layout component */
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

And you can leave your routing the same, your route will render the contact page and in turn will render your header.

This way you get control of repetitive stuff that will be on multiple pages, if you need one or two slightly different pages you can just create another layout and use that.

Comment: and in the main file should I use the same structure for routing, right?

Comment: i was thinking its not more relevant to make a Routes component and make it like this <Header/><Routes/><Footer/>?

Comment: Worth mentioning the alternative as well (of using React-Router as a component on the page, wrapping it with your `<Header>` component).

Comment: @SeanVieira which do you think makes more sense?

Comment: @Hiero I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean, could you maybe update your question with an example of what you were thinking?

Comment: @hiero I suppose what you suggest would work, in my opinion, i think it works ok if you just want one header on all pages but what if later you want to then add a footer? Then you want different headers on different pages? etc etc as it starts to get more complex using a layout technique will help keep your app more organised

Comment: I think that adding Header alongside the router will be problematic if you need to for instance hide the header on some page. You can set-up per header page and expose a prop show={true/false} and on each page if you want to hide it you just toggle it off.

this is what I currently use in a page:

`<Layout showHeader={true}>`
... stuff
</Layout>

and in Layout:

<div>
<Header show={this.props.showHeader}/>
{this.props.children}
<Footer />
</div>
`
this is just an example to try and help @Geraint get his message across :)

Comment: Still valid in 2018 in 4.0, LOVE THIS SOLUTION

Answer (score 5):

I find this way useful:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      stuff: stuff;
    };
  }
render() {
 let { stuff } = this.state;
 return (
  <Router> //wrapper for your router, given alias from BrowserRouter
   <div className="App">
    <Header /> //this component will always be visible because it is outside of a specific Route
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>  //at the root path, show this component
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={()=><Dashboard stuff={stuff} />}/>  //at the path '/dashboard', show this other component
    <Footer /> //this is also permanently mounted
   </div>
  </Router>
 );
 }
}
export default App;
```

credit goes to: [David Kerr](https://medium.com/@dkerrious/react-router-v4-1b04ec250c24)

Comment: This contains a lot of fluff, I don't see the constructor, state and stuff variable relevant to the question. Your answer seems to answer the `or can I add the header component on my ...?` question with a simple "Yes, and this is how I do it:" - is that correct? Maybe an edit is in order

Comment: What should be done to add a condition here to hide header on login ? We cannot use withrouter outside router.

Answer (score 4):

The question is already answered but I'm here to show another approach and say why I prefer that.

I also think that it's a good thing to have a Layout component

```
function Layout (props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <div className="content">
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But instead of render it into each route component you can render it just once as a parent for your routes.

```
return (
  <Router>
    <Layout>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/about">
          <About/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/contact">
          <Contact/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <Home/>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Layout>
  </Router>
);
```

This is good because in most cases you will not waste time with the layout and if you have different layouts you only need to work inside the Layout component.

Comment: Looking into this solution.  I want to have a list of available commands that each page might have and would like to do this using route metadata if I can - I know you can do this in Vue (I’m new to react).  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: What if your header has a breadcrumb, I assume given that's within the <Router> component, I can still access Router Context with hooks right?

Answer (score 1):

For forcefully refresh Header inside routing. use forceRefresh={true}

```
const Routing = () => {
        return(
            <BrowserRouter forceRefresh={true}>
            <Header/>
            <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/list/:id" component={ListingApi}/>
                    <Route path="/details/:id" component={HotelDetails}/>
                    <Route path="/booking/:hotel_name" component={PlaceBooking}/>
                    <Route path="/viewBooking" component={ViewBooking}/>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent}/>
                    <Route  path="/signup" component={RegisterComponent}/>
            </Switch>
            <Footer/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've another solution that is make the routing like this

```
const Routing = () => {
        return(
            <BrowserRouter forceRefresh={true}>
            <Header/>
            <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/list/:id" component={ListingApi}/>
                    <Route path="/details/:id" component={HotelDetails}/>
                    <Route path="/booking/:hotel_name" component={PlaceBooking}/>
                    <Route path="/viewBooking" component={ViewBooking}/>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent}/>
                    <Route  path="/signup" component={RegisterComponent}/>
            </Switch>
            <Footer/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
```

and in the header file edit as this

```
import React, {useLocation} from "react";

const header = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    return(
        <div className={location.pathname === 'login' ? 'd-none': 'd-block'}>
            abc
        </div>
    )

}
export default header;
```

this will hide the header panel in login page.