# React multi-page routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am building a multi-page app using `React`. I have three components. `Header` would appear on all pages, and `Page1` and `Page2` are to be rendered below the header as different pages. `Header` looks like this:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    return (
        <header component HTML code...>
        {this.props.children} // this is where Page1 and Page2 will render 
                              // depending on the URL 
    );
}
```

My router component looks like this (I am using the `react-router-dom` package):

```
const routes = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Header} />
      <Route path="/welcome" component={Page1} />
      <Route path="/default" component={Page2} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Accessing `/` renders the header, but `/welcome` and `/default` return a 404. I tried doing this using nested routes:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route component={Base}>
        <Route path="/welcome" component={Page1}/>
        <Route path="/landing" component={Page2}/>
    </Route>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This gives an error-

```
You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored
```

Can someone point out what I am not doing right? Is there a better way to achieve what I want here?

Comment: Have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262360/react-router-global-header

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const routes = () =>(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Route path='/welcome' exact component={Page1} />
      <Route path='/default' exact component={Page2} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

Since, we didn't specify any `Route` for the `Header`, it'll render all the time, regardless of the path