# I am having a problem accessing props in the header and footer in ReactJS. I have to use a header and footer on every page?

Tags: reactjs

I have to use a header and footer on every page. So I have given routes between Headers and Footer.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Router>
  <Header />
    <Switch>
          <Redirect exact from="/" to="dashboard" />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
          <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
        </Switch>
  <Footer/>
    </Router>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

Comment: glad everyone went to so much effort to help you only for you to totally ignore everyone's responses

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to pass props down between components in the same 'hierarchy' -- that is, components that share some form of a parent-child relationship. If I understand your issue correctly, it sounds like you would like to access certain data via props in your header and footer, which appear on each page, although they sit isolated, in a way, from your core component hierarchies established in your routes.

In a situation like this, you should consider, and I would recommend, using a local state management tool such as `Redux`, which will provide the opportunity to establish some form of global state for your application -- any component can access this data (via props) and update it as well, regardless of where it may rendered/situated -- this would include your header and footeer. You can take a look at the docs [here](https://redux.js.org/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<Router>
 <div>
 <Header />
  <Switch>
      <Redirect exact from="/" to="dashboard" />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
      <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
    </Switch>
  <Footer/>
 </div>
</Router>
```

wrap inside div

Comment: https://medium.com/@dkerrious/react-router-v4-1b04ec250c24
need more  details refer this link

Answer (score 0):

okay you can do it in two ways, first one is wrap your routes inside a container, like so

```
 class App extends Component {
 render() {
  return(
  <Router>
 <div>
 <Header />
 <Switch>
      <Redirect exact from="/" to="dashboard" />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
      <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
    </Switch>
   <Footer/>
   </div>
  </Router>
  )
  }
  }
  export default App
```

but i would recommend using a layout for your App, you can do something like this,
Layout component

```
return(
   <div>
      <Header /> // appear on every page
         { this.props.children }
      <Footer /> // appear on every page
   </div>
);
```

than you can wrap your every component in this layout

```
return (
    <Layout>
       <Dashboard />
    </Layout>
);
```

one more thing, i think your login and register page won't have the same Header or do they?
You can look at [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262360/react-router-global-header)
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think that only Greg Brodzik has really understood what you are asking in his answer above just wanted to give another solution which is to use the Context API (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Much quicker and easier to setup and use than going full Redux on an app.

Create a Provider and wrap your app:

```
<AppProvider>
  <App />
</AppProvider>
```

Inside your AppProvider you setup state and pass that as a value to everything inside the Provider:

```
this.state = {
  myVar: 'someVal',
  setValue: (value) => this.setState({ myVar: value })
}
...
<AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
  {children}
</AppContext.Provider>
```

Now any component that you want to access the value or even update that value if you include a set method in the Provider can have access:

```
import AppContext from './AppContext'
...
const context = useContext(AppContext)
const { myVar, setValue } = context
console.log(myVar) // returns 'someVal'
// update myVar
setValue('newVal')
```

Hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props in component that want to use in Header component like

```html
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Router>
  <Header test={this.props.test} />
    <Switch>
          <Redirect exact from="/" to="dashboard" />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
          <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
        </Switch>
  <Footer test={this.props.test} />
    </Router>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

You can access test from props in header and footer component