# ReactJS - Load different component when go to new page

Tags: reactjs

Good evening to all. I am new to ReactJS and I do not understand how I can load different content per page and at the same time have some fixed sections such as the header ( after click a LINK ).

I have created three components and I render them to the homepage.When I click the about link I would like to load Header & Learn.js component ONLY. How can I manage that?

Thanks a lot!

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


import Header from './components/header'
import MiddleMan from './components/middleman'
import BottomHero from './components/bottomhero'
import './web.css';


function App(){
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Header />
            <MiddleMan />
            <BottomHero />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector(".container"));
```

**middleman.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Learn from './learn';

import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Routes,
    Route,
    Link,
  } from "react-router-dom";

class MiddleMan extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="middle JV--row JV--a--center JV--spacer">
                <Router>
                    <ul>
                        <li><Link to="about">ABOUT ME</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="project">PROJECTS</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="exp">PR. LANGUAGES / TECHNOLOGIES</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="about" element={<Learn/>}></Route>
                    </Routes>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MiddleMan;
```

**learn.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './header'

class Learn extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return (
            <h2>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</h2>
        );
    }

}
export default Learn;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app structure is a little weird considering how `react-router-dom` is meant to be used. I'd suggest you read their [documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/primary-components)!

Now, trying to give a more specific answer, you should wrap your `App` component in a `BrowserRouter`. Your routes could be inside a [Switch component](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) and to implement this `Header` behavior that you wish to achieve I suggest you check the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262360/react-router-global-header).