# Import react component and add to dom automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, angular-storybook, mdxjs

I am trying to run my jsx within a javascript file like this:

```js
import React from 'react'

export class HeaderNav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log('Created Component')
  }
}

console.log('Create New Component');
<HeaderNav />
```

I then have an mdx file that imports the react component like this:

```
import '../mdx/header-nav'
```

This doesn't create the component and only `Create New Component` is output to the console, and I would expect both `console.logs` to print.

---

When I import the component into my MDX file, and place the html then it works just fine:

```js
import React from 'react'

export class HeaderNav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log('Created Component')
  }
}
```

I then have an mdx file that imports the react component like this:

```
import { HeaderNav } from '../mdx'

<HeaderNav />
```

This creates the component and outputs `Created Component` in the console.

---

Is there something that I need to do to use the first method of importing the file so I don't have to place the element in all of my mdx files?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only

This should answer your question

Comment: That doesn't seem to be related...

Comment: If you are using something like `react-router`, [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53338344/10067393) might be useful; you wouldn't even need to import `HeaderNav` into your individual components.

Comment: I am not (personally), I am using storybook so maybe storybook does?